# How to display syntax errors in JS embedded in HTML in Brackets?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, codepen

I'm working on creating a website in JavaScript and HTML. I would like to have JavaScript code in HTML files using `<script></script>`. When I use IDEs like Brackets, it does not show errors such as syntax errors in the JavaScript code. When I use CodePen it does; however, I'm not sure if CodePen would be useful for creating a website (if it is, then that might be a good choice for me instead). Does anyone know how to see those errors so I can debug the JavaScript code within HTML, whether on Brackets or some other IDE? Thanks!

Comment: Better use external javascript files instead of <script> tags (use good practices!). In your browser (let's say Chrome), put F12 to open de DevTools. In the tabs, look for "Sources". You can open there your JS files and debug it. Also, errors will be logged in the console. There are a lot of IDEs, I always recommend the ones from JetBrains, but you should try and choose your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that codepen supports syntax check for javascript by putting html and js in separate windows (maybe internally separate files). Try putting js and html in separate files and use a `<script src=""></script>` in html to refer to the js code. Than enjoy the syntax check in the separated js file, your IDE should support this.

Comment: The issue I've had with using a separate file with Brackets is that commands such as console.log() which are understood when it is JavaScript within HTML is no longer recognized.

Comment: I ended up switching over to VS Code and using live preview and everything works now.

Comment: Glad that you solved it. VS code is an awesome IDE, have fun. :)